# ModuleNotFoundError для модуля с __init__

Tags: python

С такой структурой папки

```
.
├── bot
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── orm.py
|   ├── ...
```

Из текущей папки вызываю `python -i bot/orm.py` и получаю `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bot'`

С чего это? Нахожусь не в папке модуля, у `bot` есть `__init__.py`

На `Windows` всё работало, а на `Linux Mint 20` проблема

**P.S.**

Не знаю, влияет или нет, но у меня стоит алиас `python=python3` для третьего питона

**P.S.2**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/dhvcc/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages']
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python3'
```

И

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/dhvcc/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Раз "На Windows всё работало", значит у вас проблема воспроизводится на другой системе? Какой именно? Укажите точные пути, где расположен модуль и откуда вы запускаете скрипт. Приведите вывод переменной окружения PATH, а так же свойства `sys.path`

Comment: @cauf я же показал расположение модуля отноительно моей рабочей директории, она обозначена точкой, это и есть "текущая папка"

Comment: Переменная окружения `PYTHONPATH=.` должна помочь и без установки

Answer (score 0):

Есть два решения:

1. Установить этот модуль в девелопер моде через `pip install -e .`
2. Добавить в файл {виртуальное окружение}/bin/activate строку `PYTHONPATH=.` (комментарий [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal))